# SwiftUI Preview incorrectly tries to build conditional dependency from another platform

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, swiftui, swift-package-manager

SwiftUI Previews are broken for me when one of imported Swift Package has a conditional dependency to another platform.

**Steps to reproduce:**

1. Create Xcode Project with 2 targets. One for macOS, another for iOS.
2. Add a Swift Package that has a conditional dependency - eg. depends on another package but only on iOS.
   Example:

```
targets: [
   .target(name: "Components",
           dependencies: [
           .productItem(name: "FloatingPanel", package: "FloatingPanel", condition: .when(platforms: [.iOS])),
      ]),
]
```

3. Try running SwiftUI preview on macOS. It won’t work.

The error I get is `no such module UIKit`.
It looks like Xcode is trying to build `FloatingPanel` dependency even though it's condition specifies iOS platform.

Is there any way to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I have the very same issue.
Condition works for other platform when building for iOS, but when building for other platrfom iOS dependencies are always included too...

Post on swift forum:
https://forums.swift.org/t/swiftpm-platform-conditional-target-dependancy-not-resolved-for-tvos/56767/2

And there are several bug reported...